# Android TextView - How to force a new line?

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView with a fixed width of 100dp, and the text is set in code. Whenever the text exceeds the width limit the TextView becomes completely blank. How can I force a new line when the text exceeded the width?

Comment: add \n in the text or don't fix the height of the textview

Comment: Try setting the textview to android:singleLine="false"

Comment: The text is set programmatically by a query, I have no control over adding the \n. The height is not fixed, only width is fixed.

Comment: I did try android:singleLine="false", still the same problem.

Comment: do you want to show the exceed text too?

Comment: Can you set the width to match_parent and see if it works?

Comment: Please share your code here, until then its hard to help you.

Comment: Please share your XML file. It's possible that another view is in the way...

Answer (score 1):

Please try this to your textview...

```
    <TextView 
     android:layout_width="100dp" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:maxLines="4" 
     android:singleLine="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this sample:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSample"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

or

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSample"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

with the text to set is a "very long text". the text is auto break lines without completely blanks like you. Please share your code for us to help you easily.